# Remove class, but slowly?

Tags: jquery, css, removeclass

So I am using jQuery to remove a class from an element, but it does it immediately. What I'd like is to have the class fade out smoothly, not so harsh.

This is the code I tried, which is not fading out at all:

```
    $(function() {
$( "a.engine" ).click(function() {
  $( "img.bg" ).removeClass( "intro_effects", 1000 );
  });
});
```

Any hints as to how to make this fade out?

Thanks much!

*** HERE IS THE SITE

http://dev.mediaslave.ca/illustraflex/

Thanks again!

Comment: I don't think you can do that. What does the class? Maybe you could use css transitions.

Comment: What does the class do that gets taken away? You may be able to use css transitions on a class that remains.

Comment: Ok so what I have is a BG image that has multiple classes assigned. BG makes it go 100%tall and wide, which is fine. intro_effects removes the Blur and Opacity change. Basically when you click the link, the background image unblurs and becomes 100% opaque. 

I'll post it on my server for you guys to see. 

Also, holy fast responses! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: For future reference, please post the CSS in question. How can we know what to animate if you don't tell us? Also, external links are supposed to be in addition to code, not a replacement for the important code. What happens if you decide to change your page or remove it all together, people looking at this information in the future will not have a good idea of what's being discussed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This CSS should animate the properties when you change the class, and you can control it with the transition duration property.

```
img.bg {
    transition-property: all;
    transition-duration: 1s;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, that worked perfectly. Never even though of using transitions!

Comment: @JeffMonk Keep in mind that if you need to support older browsers this won't work on them. For instance IE only started using these in IE 10. Here's a great resource for what browsers support what features: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions. To support old browsers I believe you can get a jQuery plugin that animates changes in CSS based on removing and adding classes. Also, it's a bad idea to animate `all` properties in a production environment, you should probably choose the specific property(ies) you want to animate. For an example I can see why `all` was used though.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use `.animate` to change the css properties, and then use `.removeClass` when the animation is complete.

Comment: `need` is a bit overstated, but this definately works. Then you can add or remove the class in the callback function for your `.animate()` call. That way you maintain the classes on the elements even though you're using `.animate()`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("a.engine").click(function() {
    $("img.bg").fadeOut( "slow", function() {
        // Animation complete 
    });
});
```

Comment: Won't this make the image fade out though? I don't want the image to fade out, I need the class thats causing the effects applied to it to fade off, leaving the unaltered image. .image_effects has a blur applied, and 20% opacity. I am trying to get those two effects to dissapear gradually, but not the image itself. 

Appreciate the help though!

Comment: Use JQuery-UI along with the JQuery for this. Here is the example:
http://api.jqueryui.com/removeclass/

Answer (score 3):

jQuery UI lets you do that with its removeClass: http://jqueryui.com/removeClass/

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `removeClass`, try using `fadeOut` instead. Something like this should work for you:

```
$(function() {
  $( "a.engine" ).click(function() {
    $( "img.bg" ).fadeOut();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Classes are not properties with transitions. They are either on, or they are off. So if you want something to fade out AND remove the class, you simply need two different commands... like so:

```
$(function() {
    $("a.engine").click(function(){
        $("img.bg").fadeOut(1000, function(){$(this).removeClass("intro_effects", 1000)});
    });
});
```

See it in action here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y92qu/1/